# How to save the 3D surface to bitmap in Flash 11 Stage3D

Tags: flash, rendering

I have been using Stage3D to create some 3D app in Flash. One of the items on my list is the ability to take a screen shot. Flash makes it easy to grab the stage content, but I can't find a way to grab the stage3D content. In DX I just used D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile. Anyone know of a way to do it in as3 and flash 11?

Answer (score 2):

The `drawToBitmapData` method of your 3d context (`Context3D`) should do what you want. Here are the [API docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display3D/Context3D.html#drawToBitmapData%28%29) for said method.

Comment: Thx, still trying to figure out how I overlooked that... now to over come the next obstacle. It appears I can only call this just before I do a context3D.present(). Otherwise I get an error "All buffers need to be cleared every frame before drawing". So I can set a flag from a button to only capture the screen that frame. But then I have to generate a new user event because FileReference.Save can only be call directly from an Event, not programatically.

Comment: @RobertFlesch Well, you could set a flag when the user presses the "capture screen" key, store the next frame to a bitmap object, play a fancy sound effect and then present the user a nice modal dialog with a thumbnail of the image and a *Save to disk* and *Discard* button ;)

Comment: Its putting lipstick on a pig, but I can see you understand the issue. And might as well make the pig look as pretty as you can! One more thing, in the screen shot I capture, it looks like it has no lighting, all the textures appear full bright. Any clues on that?

Comment: @RobertFlesch That's really strange. You should invoke `drawToBitmapData` just before you do `context3D.present()`. If that's the case, then I don't know what the issue could be.

Comment: Maybe you could fire off your render procedure when the filereference event occurs?  Or if you've rendered your entire output to a frame buffer, it would be very simple to just re-draw that frame buffer ....